# Programme quiz in c#

Tags: c#

I have created a quiz in c# and have just one problem with it, as  i go through the quiz it repeats the same question more than once in one round and don't know how to fix this as i am new to learning c#. Hope someone can help me!!

My code as follow:

```
    public DrivingTestQuestions(string Name, string Gender, string DOB, string Address, string Postcode, string Phone, string Email)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.lblName.Text = Name;
        this.Gender = Gender;
        this.DOB = DOB;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.Postcode = Postcode;
        this.Phone = Phone;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.correct = 0;
        this.position = 0;
        this.random = new Random();


        Dictionary<int, Quiz> dictionary;
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Quiz>();
        dictionary.Add(0, new Quiz("A vehicle should not send out visible smoke for more than?", "12 seconds", "10 seconds", "20 seconds", "5 seconds", "10 seconds"));
        dictionary.Add(1, new Quiz("Who can require you to undergo a breath screening test?", "An ambulance driver", "Other drivers", "Fire Crew", "A police officer", "A police officer"));
        dictionary.Add(2, new Quiz("When passing a bus displaying a School sign that has stopped to let children on or off, what should your speed be?", "20kph", "50kph", "70kph", "100kph", "20kph"));
        dictionary.Add(3, new Quiz("What is the speed limit from the time you pass an Accident sign until you have passed the crash site?", "30kph", "45kph", "25kph", "20kph", "20kph"));
        dictionary.Add(4, new Quiz("If your car was first registered before 1 January 2000, how often must you renew its warrant of fitness?", "Three Months", "Six Months", "Tweleve Months", "Twenty four Months", "Six Months"));
        dictionary.Add(5, new Quiz("What should you do when another vehicle is following you very closely?", "Move to the left and slow down to make it easier for it to pass", "Speed up so you're not holding it up", "Pump your brakes to tell them to drop back", "Put your hazard lights on", "Move to the left and slow down to make it easier for it to pass"));
        dictionary.Add(6, new Quiz("If you are driving a car, what should you do when following another vehicle in wet conditions?", "Observe the two-second rule", "Observe the four-second rule", "Observe the six-second rule", "Try to overtake so that you are not blinded by the spray", "Observe the four-second rule"));
        dictionary.Add(7, new Quiz("How many demerit points do you receive for exceeding the speed limit by 11-20kph?", "10", "20", "30", "40", "20"));
        dictionary.Add(8, new Quiz("If there are one or more yellow flashing lights at traffic signals, what does it mean?", "All cars must stop as emergency vehicles are coming through", "The lights are faulty and the Give Way rules apply", "There's a diversion ahead", "Move to the left hand side of the road", "The lights are faulty and the Give Way rules apply"));
        dictionary.Add(9, new Quiz("When passing a horse and rider, what should you do?", "Give a quick toot of the horn to warn them you're coming", "Pass as quickly as possible to avoid spooking the horse", "Slow down, giving them as much room as you can", "Turn on your headlights to warn the rider", "Slow down, giving them as much room as you can"));
        this.questions = dictionary;
        return;

    }



    public void GetQuestion()
    {

            this.position = this.random.Next(0,10);

        {

                this.lblQuestion.Text = this.questions[this.position].thequestion;
                this.radBtnOption1.Text = this.questions[this.position].option1;
                this.radBtnOption2.Text = this.questions[this.position].option2;
                this.radBtnOption3.Text = this.questions[this.position].option3;
                this.radBtnOption4.Text = this.questions[this.position].option4;
                this.ResetAll();
                return;
            }
```

Comment: `this.random = new Random();` is most likely why.  You need to seed the `Random` class with a new value every time, otherwise you get the same numbers in the same order (or darn close).

Comment: Ok not sure how to do that can you give me an example please?

Comment: I think voters are bit harsh here. This question's title maybe confusing but its not a bad question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Storing all asked questions in a seperated list**

   Then you have to make a small workaraound as the others already suggested:
   Add a `List`where you store your asked Questions: `List<int> askedQuestions = new List<int>();` and change this

   public void GetQuestion()
       {
           if(askedQuestion.Count != questions.Count)
          {
           //not nice but this should work
           do { this.position = this.rand.Next(0, 10); } while (askedQuestions.Contains(this.position));

   ```
       {

           this.lblQuestion.Text = this.questions[this.position].thequestion;
           this.radBtnOption1.Text = this.questions[this.position].option1;
           this.radBtnOption2.Text = this.questions[this.position].option2;
           this.radBtnOption3.Text = this.questions[this.position].option3; 
           this.radBtnOption4.Text = this.questions[this.position].option4;
           this.ResetAll();

           askedQuestions.add(this.position);//the question is marked as asked

           return;
       }
      }
   }
   ```

---

2. **Storing all questions in a dictionary/list and remove them**

You have a pool of questions in your dictionary and you always take one of them randomly. In order to prevent some questions from being show up twice you have to remove the questions from this pool.

For making it even simpler a `dictionary` is not the best solution: Just use a `List`and everything's allright :)

Therefor you have to change your `Dictionary` into a `List` but this should not be a big task for you. And in your particular case a `List` would be a way better solution as you are using a normal `Dictionary` as a `List`. Using a `Dictionary` would mean that your computer has to search the entry what takes time. Using a `List` means that your Computer already knows where to look up the entry.

And as you are using just normal indizes (which is exactly what a `List` does) as a key for your Dictionary it wouldn't make any difference.

```
public void GetQuestion()
    {
        if(questions.Count != 0)
        {
        this.position = this.random.Next(0, questions.Count);

        {

            this.lblQuestion.Text = this.questions[this.position].thequestion;
            this.radBtnOption1.Text = this.questions[this.position].option1;
            this.radBtnOption2.Text = this.questions[this.position].option2;
            this.radBtnOption3.Text = this.questions[this.position].option3; 
            this.radBtnOption4.Text = this.questions[this.position].option4;
            this.ResetAll();

            qestions.RemoveAt(position);//important!

            return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Another thing could be the start of a new quizz as there wont be any questions in the pool any more. I don't know how you are doing this at the moment but one possible solution would be adding the questions again:

```
    if (this.Question == 10)
            {
                SummaryofDrivingTest form = new SummaryofDrivingTest(this.lblName.Text, this.Gender, this.DOB, this.Address, this.Postcode, this.Phone, this.Email, Convert.ToString(this.correct));
                form.Show();
                this.Hide();

List<Quiz> dictionary;
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Quiz>();
        dictionary.Add(new Quiz("A vehicle should not send out visible smoke for more than?", "12 seconds", "10 seconds", "20 seconds", "5 seconds", "10 seconds"));
        dictionary.Add(new Quiz("Who can require you to undergo a breath screening test?", "An ambulance driver", "Other drivers", "Fire Crew", "A police officer", "A police officer"));
        dictionary.Add(new Quiz("When passing a bus displaying a School sign that has stopped to let children on or off, what should your speed be?", "20kph", "50kph", "70kph", "100kph", "20kph"));
        dictionary.Add(new Quiz("What is the speed limit from the time you pass an Accident sign until you have passed the crash site?", "30kph", "45kph", "25kph", "20kph", "20kph"));
        dictionary.Add(new Quiz("If your car was first registered before 1 January 2000, how often must you renew its warrant of fitness?", "Three Months", "Six Months", "Tweleve Months", "Twenty four Months", "Six Months"));
        dictionary.Add(new Quiz("What should you do when another vehicle is following you very closely?", "Move to the left and slow down to make it easier for it to pass", "Speed up so you're not holding it up", "Pump your brakes to tell them to drop back", "Put your hazard lights on", "Move to the left and slow down to make it easier for it to pass"));
        dictionary.Add(new Quiz("If you are driving a car, what should you do when following another vehicle in wet conditions?", "Observe the two-second rule", "Observe the four-second rule", "Observe the six-second rule", "Try to overtake so that you are not blinded by the spray", "Observe the four-second rule"));
        dictionary.Add(new Quiz("How many demerit points do you receive for exceeding the speed limit by 11-20kph?", "10", "20", "30", "40", "20"));
        dictionary.Add(new Quiz("If there are one or more yellow flashing lights at traffic signals, what does it mean?", "All cars must stop as emergency vehicles are coming through", "The lights are faulty and the Give Way rules apply", "There's a diversion ahead", "Move to the left hand side of the road", "The lights are faulty and the Give Way rules apply"));
        dictionary.Add(new Quiz("When passing a horse and rider, what should you do?", "Give a quick toot of the horn to warn them you're coming", "Pass as quickly as possible to avoid spooking the horse", "Slow down, giving them as much room as you can", "Turn on your headlights to warn the rider", "Slow down, giving them as much room as you can"));
        this.questions = dictionary;

                return;
            }
```

As you are knew to C# there is one point:
You don't need to always write `return` at the end of the method :)
It's perfectly alright when you're doing this but you don't need to do this (except you really have to return a value).

Comment: all i want it to do is not to let the questions in one round not repeat more than once and when i start changing stuff other errors happen

Comment: ill have another go at and get back to you thanks for your help so far if i have problems will let you know

Comment: public void GetQuestion()
        {

            if (askedQuestions.Count != questions.Count) "says here Object reference not set to an instance of an object" i done what you have shown me above
            {

Comment: This is really strange... Make sure that `List<int> askedQuestions = new List<int>();` is correct. Anyway you could set a breakpoint at this line and hover with your courser over the objects and look which of them shows `null`. But I really can't see any reason at the moment. Obviously it should be `askedQuestions` but that can't be because of the line you should check.

Comment: Yeah i dont know still coming up with some problem and i am confused with it

Comment: Have you checked which of the objects is `null`?

Comment: No how do i do that?

Comment: Use a braekpoint or write something like `if(askedQuestions == null){MessageBox.Show("Oh!");}` before this `.Count != .Count`

Comment: Hey i have got it all going now thanks heaps for your help;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, usage of `Random()` looks correct. If you do `random.Next(0,10)` it will return a random int in range [0..9]. Quite possible that the same int returns several time, even possible you get 10 zeros in a row, that is randomness.

If you want to avoid seeing the same question twice you need a slightly different algorithm:

Either mark questions as "seen" and draw another random number if you get one which is alraedy "seen".

-Or-

Keep a list of "unseen questions" and draw the next question from this list, removing it from this list after it is "done".

Answer (score 0):

The other way to solve is keep a List which stores the index of already asked questions, following is a simple example how you can avoid the already asked questions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        List<int> AlreadyAskedQuestions = new List<int>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<10;i++)
        {
            int rn = rnd.Next(0,10);
            while(AlreadyAskedQuestions.Contains(rn))
            {
                rn = rnd.Next(0,10);
            }
            AlreadyAskedQuestions.Add(rn);
        }

        foreach(int i in AlreadyAskedQuestions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```